# OrgMode show schedules in calendar for date selection

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have the following problem/question: I am using OrgMode in emacs to schedule all my appointments. I usually do this in the following way:

```
* Some Headline
** Appointment 1
<2016-10-27 09:00--10:00>
** Appointment 2
<2016-10-28 10:00--12:00>
.... and so on
```

This works great so far and I see all my appointments in the agenda popping up as they are supposed to. I also use calfw (https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw) which produces a pretty nice overview.

However now my question: When I use the orgmode shortcut for inserting a timestamp at an entry in the org-file, the emacs-calendar pops up, where I can navigate through the calendar and set the date. However, I cannot see the scheduled entries for the dates during navigation. Is there some easy way to setup the calendar to show the appointments from the OrgMode-file (and also the emacs diary) in this calendar? In the ideal case, another buffer should open and provide a brief overview of the appointments for the day under the cursor.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Aside from a suggestion that you may wish to start using DEADLINE and SCHEDULED entries (instead of time-stamps with no labels), you may wish to spend some time clarifying what you mean by:  "*I cannot see the scheduled entries for the dates during navigation.*"  And, it appears you have a second question dealing with showing appointments from both the `diary` and a standard org-mode file.  Lastly, the people who read this forum (especially the *emacs* tag) are hard-core programmers who prefer to see only strict programming questions with sample code.  Try:  emacs.stackexchange.com